Copi tokens missing from my metamask wallet
I had 10000 Copi tokens in my Metamask wallet and they are all transferred to 'PancakeSwap V2: COPI 5' and can see a transaction history. But I didn't initiate this. Could someone help me understand where my tokens are and how this happened? I would love to retrieve it. I checked pancakeswap.finance and can't see my tokens there as well. I am really worried if my wallet is hacked.

Can you provide more details? like addresses of the wallet, or tokens involved. Also it could be a scam token.

It was a scam. Someone gained access to my phrase from my laptop and transferred my funds using pancakeswap.

Sorry for you loss. Fake tokens have been active from the very beginning. Don't forget to do your own research before investing in any crypto active.
